# Which output method shoud I use for logging system?

Tags: c++, networking

I am working on a server programming on linux machine using epoll. I am printing log statements using `printf()`, but I was wondering which output method uses the least system resources.

As you guys already know, server programming deals with a lot of log statements so I was wondering the best output method I should use. Possible candidates are `printf` `cout` etc..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Embarrassing admission:  I just use fprintf wrapped in a macro, which I duplicate once for each log file.  This solution is not amazing, but it is simple, works and lets me get on with my life without spending more time than necessary thinking about the banality of logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `printf` and `cout` are console output methods, neither is going to trouble your CPU greatly, you are probably worrying about nothing.

However C++ provides three standard output streams - `cout`, `cerr`, and `clog`.  I suggest that you should use the latter since that is what it is for, and the output of your log is then system defined.

If you do not need output formatting, then it will be marginally (and probably not measurably) faster to use `fwrite()`, `puts()`, or `clog.write()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++, You can use **[log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)** for logging. It is a pretty decent framework, though you may think of simply getting around using crude or self implemented logging techniques in the long run a decent logging framework can save a lot of trouble when your project goes bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the performance, but this may work (untested)
I've heard using `/n` is faster than `std::endl` too

```
ofstream logfile;
logfile.open("log.txt");
log <<"log text";
```

Comment: they do different things. std::endl flushes the stream as well as writing a new line char

Answer (score 0):

If your application create a lot of logs and logging statements are affecting performance, a quick solution would be to create a small process that has a queue which can be filled over a socket connection.  The logging process can write to disk at regular intervals or when its input queue is full.

If even the extra disk access is affecting performance,  then the logging process can be run on a smaller server connected to the same switch as the app server.

Or if you don't want the message passing latency and don't mind writing slightly more complex code,  you can use a logging thread instead.

Comment: She's running on a Linux machine. There's such a process already, and it's called "syslogd". why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using [syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog)? I think that's the obvious answer to your question, unless you have some compelling reason against it.

Comment: One problem I had with syslog on a system is they wanted to have applications log to different files. So they used facility local0. It worked fine until they got to local7 and needed more applications. Also other programs started to use local0...

Comment: @rve the  good thing with syslog is that it logs the process ID, so you can post-process the files as you wish. I never had to use more than 2 facilities (usually I use 1 for logging which is LOG_USER, 1 for errors as LOG_LOCAL0, 1 for debugs when needed as LOG_LOCAL1, to separate the level of logging, that's it). I grep what I need based on prefix.